# How to detect a flash / Glare in an image of document using skimage / opencv in python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

**Please suggest a new approach or at least a method to make any of these robust enough to detect at  good rate**

I have some images (mostly taken from computer screen) where some kind of flash from camera or so called is present there. I want to discard these type of images or at least notify the user to retake it. How could I do that?

I do not have enough to train a Deep Learning Classification model such as [Fast Glare Detection](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.05189.pdf)

[Here is the Data of more than 70 images](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JhlRiVNbnJlqTmI1bkD7Jwrpkh1stxRn/view?usp=sharing)

I have tried these few things in order:

1. [Bright area detection using OpenCV `cv2.minMaxLoc` function](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/29/finding-brightest-spot-image-using-python-opencv/) but it ALWAYS returns the area no matter what and mostly it fails for my type of images.
2. I found [this code for removal but it is in Matlab](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1215/how-to-remove-a-glare-clipped-brightness-from-an-image)
3. [This code uses `Clahe` adjustement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470569/remove-glare-from-photo-opencv) but the problem is that it removes rather than detection
4. [This one looks promising but is not robust enough for my image type](https://rcvaram.medium.com/glare-removal-with-inpainting-opencv-python-95355aa2aa52)

The final below code I found is somewhat I need but can someone help me for making it robust. for example using these thresholds / changing them / or using Binarization , Closing (Increasing White area with dilation and then removing black Noise with Erosion) such that these are generalised for all.

```
def get_image_stats(img_path):
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (25, 25), 0)
    no_text = gray * ((gray/blurred)>0.99)                     # select background only
    no_text[no_text<10] = no_text[no_text>20].mean()           # convert black pixels to mean value
    no_bright = no_text.copy()
    no_bright[no_bright>220] = no_bright[no_bright<220].mean() # disregard bright pixels

    std = no_bright.std()
    bright = (no_text>220).sum()

    if no_text.mean()<200 and bright>8000:
        return True
```

These are some of few examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about gamma correction with a high gamma value? It is a non-linear transform on pixel intensities as shown in the OpenCV tutorial on image intensity transformations [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc1/tutorial_basic_linear_transform.html). Check what is gamma correction in the aforementioned OpenCV link.

I tried this on your images with a very high gamma value. The code is as follows.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import os

gamma = 50
lookuptable = np.empty((1, 256), np.uint8)
lookuptable[0, :] = [np.clip(pow(i/255.0, 10)*255.0, 0, 255) for i in range(256)]

for img_file in os.listdir():
    if 'jpg' in img_file:
        img = cv.imread(img_file, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        res = cv.LUT(img, lookuptable)
        filename_gamma = f"{img_file.split('.')[0]}_{gamma}.jpg"
        cv.imwrite(filename_gamma, res)

        __, ret = cv.threshold(res, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY+cv.THRESH_OTSU)
        filename_bin = f"{img_file.split('.')[0]}_{gamma}_bin.jpg"
        cv.imwrite(filename_bin, ret)
```

The results are as follows. In pairs the top is gamma corrected image and the bottom is thresholding on the gamma corrected image.
[image: gamma-corrected] [image: Otsu threshold after gamma correction]

[image: gamma-corrected] [image: Otsu threshold after gamma correction]

[image: gamma-corrected] [image: Otsu threshold after gamma correction]

You can apply a more manual thresholding on the gamma corrected image to get better results if you have images of the last type such as set only grayscale values in the range (245-255) as foreground.

Once that is done you can extract statistics about these extracted glare zones using connected component analysis.